# Rearranging hierarchy - move the following-sibling of an element before the end of that element

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I need to rearrange hierarchy (move lists that appear after the para, inside of the para):

```
From: <para updated="20240205"><text> ...  </text> ... </para><list type="num"> ... </list>
To: <para updated="20240205"><text> ... </text> ... <list type="num"> ... </list></para>
```

**Notes:**

- The DTD allows para's to contain lists and lists can also contain para's
- There could be multiple lists following the para that need to be moved to the end of the preceding para

I am relatively new to XSL and am unsure of how to handle this being that these are currently siblings

I did not try anything yet because I was not sure how to approach this.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to at least include a small sample set of data and the required output from that same input. Good luck.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning in the title of "move the following-sibling of an element before the end of that element" end of "that" what is "that" the element or the following sibling, the parent or some other concept?  This whole `...` in the example does not help much to enhance clarity  Perhaps put them as CODE blocks (formatted as code) with actual content not ... so you have "Before" "After/Desired output" samples and "code I tried" to show your effort here as separate blocks

Comment: 1. Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports. 2. Do you know anything about XSLT? This is not a very difficult task.

Comment: Looks like a simple `xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="para"`. Tons of examples of that on StackOverflow alone. How easy it is of course depends on whether there are other elements than the `para` and `list` siblings and how to treat them.

Comment: Having said that, XSLT questions should always say if you are constrained to use a particular version of XSLT. This kind of problem is much easier in XSLT 2.0+, but there are many people still using legacy XSLT 1.0 processors.

Comment: I did start writing an answer, but it's so dependent on XSLT version that I decided to wait until you had supplied that information.

Comment: I use XSLT version 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="*[para]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="para">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::para">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node(), tail(current-group())"/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I think `tail` is XPath 3/XSLT 3 so if you are really using an XSLT 2 processor use `subsequence(current-group(), 2)` instead.

Of course pushing everything through `apply-templates` assumes you have the identity transformation (template) set up for the nodes you don't want to change and add templates for any transformation on nodes you want to change.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance but how would I limit this to only <list>'s that appear after a para?

Comment: @ChrisR, consider to edit your question and show the possible variations of input and wanted result data. I don't know where your other `list` elements are or what exactly you want to limit as you have not explained which other elements can be present and where they can be present in the input and where you want to place them in the result.

Comment: There are many other elements that I do not want to include in the rearranging. The <para>'s can be followed by <head>'s, <table>'s etc. which I do not want to rearrange. The problem is that the DTD that governs this data is large and complex and I would not be able to provide every possible xpath. The logic you provided seems to work well but moves any and all following-siblings of the para before the end of the para. Is there a way to specify to only move the lists that appear as following siblings of the para before the </para> and leave the rest alone?

Comment: Would I need a identity transformation match for each and every possible element.

Comment: @ChrisR, it is possible to replace e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node(), subsequence(current-group(), 2)"/>` with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node(), subsequence(current-group(), 2)[self::list]"/>` and then to add (after the closing `</xsl:copy>`) an `<xsl:apply-templates select="subsequence(current-group(), 2)[not(self::list)]"/>`. But it is still not clear how the `list` and other elements can appear and whether you want to pull any list into the preceding para or only any immediately following ones, not in any way separated by other siblings.

Comment: @ChrisR, as for the identity transformation template, well, in XSLT 3 you declare it as `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` and in XSLT 2 you write it as e.g. `<xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`, that would then take care of copying anything not being matched by more specific templates.

Comment: I would only need to pull the lists immediately following the para before that para's end tag. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like the changes you recommended above are dropping any other elements that appear as following-siblings to the para's

Comment: It looks like it is also dropping some content of the lists

Comment: @Chris, as I said, edit your question and provide the relevant samples, I can only suggest and write code for samples I see, I am not going to try to invent variants of the sample. If the input has a complex structure and the `para` is kind of not the "anchor" you want to tie everything to, it might be that the whole suggestion is inadequate, but it was made based on the sample provided.

Comment: The para is the anchor. I have a small sample with before and after. I am unsure of the best way to get those to you to look at.

Comment: @Chris, consider to ask a new question with the necessary details (the input(s) you have, the current XSLT you use, the result you want, the one you get), that is usually more successful and fruitful than trying to refine something here in extended comments.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
<!-- By habit, I always say what I expect my mode's behavior should be, by default. 
    Helps avoid unexpected leaks. -->
<xsl:mode name="my-mode" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:mode name="another-mode" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<!-- First, set up the template rule that drops lists to be moved. In this case I've picked 
    the lists that have a para as a sibling, and have @type as num. Plus you'd better make
    sure there's a para before that can pick up the list. -->
<xsl:template match="*[para]/list[@type eq 'num'][exists(preceding-sibling::para)]"
    mode="my-mode"/>

<!-- Now just tuck the relevant following siblings into your template. -->
<xsl:template match="*[list[@type eq 'num']]/para" mode="my-mode">
    <xsl:variable name="next-para" as="element()?" select="following-sibling::para[1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lists-to-append" as="element()*" select="following-sibling::list[@type eq 'num'] 
        except $next-para/following-sibling::*"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$lists-to-append" mode="another-mode"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You'll need to make sure you've nailed down the logic for what constitutes a list that should be moved, versus those that shouldn't.

If there's a lot of logic involved in sorting out which lists should or should not be moved, I frequently do a first pass, with its own mode, to handle the logic. In that pass I put inside each `list` a temporary attribute, e.g., `<list _moveme="">...</list>`. Then the mode `my-mode` can focus on those lists with that attribute. Don't forget to remove those attributes in the `another-mode` pass, though (unless you want to keep a record).